# How to use str_split() in R?

Tags: r, stringr

I want to split this string in several substrings:

> BAA33520.2|/gene="vpf402",/product="Vpf402"|GI:8272373|AB012574|join{7347:7965,
>   0:591}

The separator is | (ascii 124).
It works with all other separators but not with this one.

Comment: PS: the split function wont split that string at all when the | is used as separator.

Comment: What did you try that failed?

Comment: Did you try escaping it?  i.e., `\\|`

Answer (score 5):

`?regex`

> *Two regular expressions may be joined by the infix operator `|`; the resulting regular expression matches any string matching either subexpression. For example, `abba|cde` matches either the string `abba` or the string `cde`. Note that alternation does not work inside character classes, where `|` has its literal meaning.*
>
> *The fundamental building blocks are the regular expressions that match a single character. Most characters, including all letters and digits, are regular expressions that match themselves. Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are `. \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?`, but note that whether these have a special meaning depends on the context.*

Thus:

```
stringr::str_split('BAA33520.2|/gene="vpf402",/product="Vpf402"|GI:8272373|AB012574|join{7347:7965, 0:591}', "\\|")
```

As @[Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) noted, you can do this in `base::strsplit()` by adding the `fixed=TRUE`:

```
strsplit('BAA33520.2|/gene="vpf402",/product="Vpf402"|GI:8272373|AB012574|join{‌​7347:7965, 0:591}',"|", fixed=TRUE)
```

However, you can also do this with `stringr::str_split()` by decorating the regular expression for the separator:

```
stringr::str_split('BAA33520.2|/gene="vpf402",/product="Vpf402"|GI:8272373|AB012574|join{7347:7965, 0:591}', 
                   regex("|", literal=TRUE))
```

Incidentally, `stringr` is pretty much just a *slightly* friendlier wrapper to `stringi` functions at this point and I highly recommend studying the `stringi` package as it contains some wonderful gems outside of string spiltting.

Comment: In base R, you can also set fixed=TRUE to get around this `strsplit('BAA33520.2|/gene="vpf402",/product="Vpf402"|GI:8272373|AB012574|join{7347:7965, 0:591}',"|", fixed=TRUE)`. Seems that option wasn't included in stringr.